# How to assign django permissions for object creators?

Tags: python, django, object, admin, user-permissions

is it possible to allow editing on django admin site of objects in database only for creators of these objects? is extension django-guardian essential for this case? as i understood with django guardian i need manually assign permissions for each db objects and it seems not effective

I tried to use django-guardian for this case, but documentation for it is not very clear for me and I am not sure this extension solve this case

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `has_change_permission`, `has_delete_permission`, etc. on your model admin class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/

You will also need to handle setting the object's creator yourself on save.

It might look something like this:

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.creator = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True

        return request.user == obj.creator
```